# Image map with image size 100%

Tags: html, css

What are my options if I'm creating an image map based on an image that's sized 100%? Are there any solutions for having the coordinates of the "area" recalculated based upon the size of the browser?

Comment: I haven't either, but have you tried percentages? They might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-write all of the coordinates in the image map to scale the values. You can do this using JavaScript.

Comment: I want to do this with jQuery.  How would I calculate the coordinates relative to the size of the browser?

Comment: Base it on the size of the original vs. zoomed image. Scale them in proportion

Comment: for each number you would do this `c = c * (currentTreeWidth / originalTreeWidth)`. Split and join the `coords` attribute. This should be recalculated on every resize on the image, and possibly every `window` resize.